# What it means **/node_modules/* in tsconfig.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

In [this official docs of Visual Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript) it's recommended to add `node_modules` to the `exclude` field of tsconfig.json. It is done this way:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

I wonder why `**/node_modules/*` is needed if I'm already adding the plain `node_modules` folder.

Comment: It's to exclude any `node_modules` sub-folders (at any depth) of the stuff in the root level `node_modules` folder.

Comment: don't try to look for files to compile in folders that match the glob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`**/node_modules/*` is a glob pattern meaning (from right to left) "anything under a `node_modules` directory *at any depth*". See the [`glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) module for more details, it's highly likely it's the module used to interpret that pattern.

From their docs:

- `*` Matches 0 or more characters in a single path portion
- `**` If a "globstar" is alone in a path portion, then it matches zero or more directories and subdirectories searching for matches. It does not crawl symlinked directories.

Comment: Great explanation, but why the first "node_modules" entry when just the "**/node_modules/*" would have sufficed?